# Quiero en una misma consulta SQL Server crear un campo con valor si o no dependiendo de si en otra tabla existen registros

Tags: sql, sql-server, server

quiero incluir en una consulta un campo con valor 0 o 1 dependiendo de si la id de la tabla1 (yusers) existe en la tabla2 (Seleccion_Cuadrantes). Ahora mismo lo he conseguido hacer mediante un procedimiento almacenado pero me quiero ahorrar el tener que llamar al procedimiento en cada registro si, de una sola consulta, ya dispongo del resultado. Gracias, saludos.

Os adjunto el código del procedimiento. Querría hacerlo en una consulta sql, sin necesidad, a ser posible, de crear campo alguno en la tabla 1:

```
USE [BD-Yusers]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[verificarExistencia] @Id_user INT
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM Seleccion_Cuadrantes 
           WHERE Id_user = @Id_user) 
BEGIN
 SELECT 1 Resultado 
END
ELSE BEGIN 
 SELECT 0 Resultado
END
```

Comment: Tienes que proporcionar tu código si el no te podemos ayudar!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Creo que ahora está mucho más comprensible, ya me comentaréis. I'm sorry !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede ser con la funcionalidad CASE:

En el siguiente ejemplo 'campo' será evaluado y retornará '0' si contiene la palabra 'falso' sino retornará '1'

Select CASE WHEN campo = 'falso' THEN '0' ELSE '1' END from ....

Comment: Muy buenas Luis, gracias por tu respuesta. La duda és campo ha de existir en la tabla yusers? Existe la posibilidad de hacer la comprobación sin necesidad de crear dicho campo? Gracias de nuevo, saludos.